# 2 response.setHeader on 1 JSP

Tags: html, jsp, httpresponse

Is it not possible to keep 2 `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=r.pdf");` and `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=rt.pdf");`on one JSP page?
I need to have either one of them downloaded and other one to be displayed on the web page.Isnt it possible?Both need to give output simultaneously as both are corelated to each other.

Comment: Nope. That is not possible.

Comment: @AVD or else any other alternative to it.I tried with file input stream,but there i need to give the path in text which isnt user friendly